# Finding the joint unconditional distribution of $X$ and $Y=N-X$ for $X\sim \mathrm{Bin}(N,p)$ and $N\sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The question asks to find the unconditional joint distribution of $X$ and $Y=N-X$, given that

- $N$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$, and
- $X$ has a conditional distribution $\mathrm{Bin}(N,p)$.

I have worked out that $X$ has an unconditional distribution $\mathrm{Pois}(p\lambda)$ though I'm not sure that is of much help.

I am having trouble beginning. The steps I used to find the single unconditional distribution were straightforward, but I'm not sure how to go about it for the joint distribution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to find the same thing. How did you find that $X$ has an unconditional distribution $Pois(p\lambda)$? Thanks in advance, Meg

Answer (score 3):

You have been given the conditional probability mass of $X\mid N$, so why not use it?

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X=k, Y=h) & = \mathsf P(X=k, N-X=h)
\\ & = \mathsf P(X=k, N=h+k)
\\ & = \mathsf P(X=k\mid N=h+k)\cdot \mathsf P(N=h+k)
\\ & = \binom{h+k}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{h}\cdot\frac{\lambda^{h+k}e^{-\lambda}}{(h+k)!}
\end{align}$

Comment: Ah thanks a lot Graham, I've spent far too long trying to work out some sort of sum, going in the totally wrong direction. Thanks, if I could upvote I would.